# "Click-through" GLFW window?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, overlay, glfw

i have a little problem setting up my glfw overlay properly, i already successfully created an glfw window with transparent background , now i want to make the window also "click-through" so i can access the windows behind it and let it act like an overlay.

sadly i cant figure out how to do this in glfw, my current code to init the window looks like that:

```
Width = 3440;
Height = 1440;
/* GLFW */
if (!glfwInit()) {
    fprintf(stdout, "[GLFW] failed to init!\n");
    exit(1);
}
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GLFW_FALSE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_FOCUSED, GLFW_FALSE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_FOCUS_ON_SHOW, GLFW_FALSE);

/*Topmost and see through*/
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_FLOATING, GLFW_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER, GLFW_TRUE);

glfwSwapInterval(1);
Window = glfwCreateWindow(Width, Height, "Overlay", 0, 0);
glfwMakeContextCurrent(Window);
```

i also tried with glfw3_native.h given glfwGetX11Window function and tried to do stuff like

```
void Render::MakeClickable(bool State){
    auto X11Window = glfwGetX11Window(Window);
    if(State){

    }else{
        XserverRegion region = XFixesCreateRegion (MainDisplay, NULL, 0);
        XFixesSetWindowShapeRegion (MainDisplay, X11Window, ShapeInput, 0, 0, region);
        XFixesDestroyRegion (MainDisplay, region);
    }
}
```

but that didn't worked :/

How can I setup my window correctly to ignore my click and let it pass to the windows behind, so i can use it as an overlay?

Answer (score 7):

a new window hint `GLFW_MOUSE_PASSTHROUGH` was added to GLFW [recently](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/pull/1568) to enable this feature.

you can use it like that:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_MOUSE_PASSTHROUGH, GLFW_TRUE);
```